# Integrating basic android source code into Ecplise

Tags: android

I downloaded the Android SDK and the Eclipse Plugin and installed them. When I however use the "Open Declaration" in Eclipse on basic Android functions and classes such as setOnClickListener or ListActivity it gives me an "Source not found"-Error.

The total Android source code seems to be 2.1 GB. Where do I get the source code of those functions that I call with the API to integrate it into Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=979) issue. There is a lot of links explaining how to do it.

Comment: Thanks. And for a quicker shortcut, this person has already done the work for 1.5, 1.6 and 2.1: http://android.opensourceror.org/2010/01/18/android-source/

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

The source code is not included with the sdk. If you wish to debug/use android source you need to download it separately from the sdk. It can be found on google's official site [here](http://source.android.com/). This site also contains important information about using their source code that you should read.

Was this helpful?

Comment: Your link goes to a page about contributing to the source. That's not what I want. I just want to feel like I'm not using black boxes.


When I for example download JDK there an extra link to load the documentation and to load the source code at http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp. I would want to have  something of a similar structure for android.

Comment: i believe the site i provided includes the actual source code as well as some tools for using it. If you look on the left side it says "getting the source" which takes you here: http://source.android.com/source/download.html

Answer (score 0):

You can see the source code by installing a plugin in Eclipse: http://adt-addons.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/source/com.android.ide.eclipse.source.update/