# Source code of widgets

Tags: android

How do you view the source code of widgets? I'm trying to make a custom spinner by extending Spinner and am curious to see the original code.

In Eclipse, I've looked in Android 2.2 > android.jar > android.widget > Spinner.class but it tells me source not found.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Integrating basic android source code into Ecplise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127363/integrating-basic-android-source-code-into-ecplise)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old question about spinners. (shows code) [How can I extend spinner to implement a new function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528976/how-can-i-extend-spinner-to-implement-a-new-function)

I would imagine that you only have to extend the class, define a custom layout and have it do what you want your spinner to do.